# ASP.NET MVC Core WebAPI project not returning html

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

Here is my controller i am sending my html

```
      public class MyModuleController : Controller
        {
            // GET: api/values
            [HttpGet]
            public HttpResponseMessage Get()
            {


                var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
                response.Content = new StringContent("<html><body>Hello World</body></html>");
                response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
                return response;
            }
}
```

In response i am getting this

```
    {"version":{"major":1,"minor":1,"build":-1,"revision":-1,

"majorRevision":-1,"minorRevision":-1},"content":{"headers":[{"key":"Content-Type","value":["text/plain;

 charset=utf-8"]}]},"statusCode":200,"reasonPhrase":"OK","headers":[],"requestMessage":null,"isSuccessStatusCode":true}
```

I just want my html in output.Please can anyone help,Thanku

Comment: That is an Mvc controller, not an apicontroller. Change your base class to `ApiController` first.

Comment: @Mathew - If you use asp.net core, all of them are derived from Controller class

Comment: Ok, sorry, I dont have enough exp in core.

Comment: Do you have to return html from the API? The API generally for returning data and not HTML.

Comment: Yes i want to return HTML,

Comment: Can It be static file?

Comment: But i dont want to return a file,its a static content

Comment: If it static content create html file under your wwwroot folder and try to browse there usually it will work. Than you can send request to api-address/file-name.html it will return you content of that html file. If it does not work read this https://jonhilton.net/2016/08/25/how-to-serve-static-files-for-your-single-page-application-from-net-core/ it's the simplest way to do it

Comment: No i want to do this by string,because my HTML string will come from SP (sql)

Comment: I know it work this way .. return View("~/Views/Index.cshtml");

Comment: try to do it this way 
[HttpGet]
public ContentResult Get()
 {
            return Content("<b>a</b>", "text/html");
} 
It worked for me once in .NET Core

Comment: I tried this  return Content("<html><body>Hello World</body></html>","text/html"); It returned me a string No HTML

Comment: Sorry Thanku it worked

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [`ContentResult`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ContentResult.cs), which inherits [`ActionResult`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ActionResult.cs). Just remember to set `ContentType` to `text/html`.

```
public class MyModuleController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var content = "<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1><p>Some text</p></body></html>";

        return new ContentResult()
        {
            Content = content,
            ContentType = "text/html",
        };
    }
}
```

It will return a correct Content-Type:

[image]

Which will cause the browser to parse it as HTML:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Thanku to @genichm and @smoksnes,this is my working solution

```
    public class MyModuleController : Controller
        {
            // GET: api/values
            [HttpGet]
            public ContentResult Get()
            {
                //return View("~/Views/Index.cshtml");

                return Content("<html><body>Hello World</body></html>","text/html");
            }
  }
```